# How do I get a JPanel with an empty JLabel to take up space in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am  working on a GUI for a project at school. I am using a GridBagLayout in swing.

I want to have a label indicating the input(a type of file @ x = 0, y = 0), followed by another label(the actual file name once selected @ `x = 1, y = 0`), followed by a browse button for a file chooser( @ `x = 2, y = 0`). The label at `(1,0)` is initially blank, however I want the area that the text will occupy to take up some space when the label contains no text. I also want the space between the label at `(0,0)` and the button at `(2,0)` to remain constant.

To achieve this, I'm trying to put the label onto a panel and then play with the layouts. However I can't seam to achieve the desired results. Could anyone offer some suggestions? The next three rows of the GridBagLayout will be laid out exactly the same way.

Here is a link to a screen shot of the GUI.

[image: The pic]

```
    calibrationFileSelectionValueLabel = new JLabel("",Label.LEFT);
    calibrationFileSelectionValueLabel.setName("calibrationFileSelection");
    calibrationFileSelectionValueLabel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,0));



    calibrationFileSelectionValuePanel = new JPanel();
    calibrationFileSelectionValuePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    calibrationFileSelectionValuePanel.add(calibrationFileSelectionValueLabel);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    filesPanel.add(calibrationFileLabel,c);

    c.gridy = 1;
    filesPanel.add(frequencyFileLabel,c);

    c.gridy = 2;
    filesPanel.add(sampleFileLabel,c);

    c.gridy = 3;
    filesPanel.add(outputFileLabel,c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

   // filesPanel.add(calibrationFileSelection,c);
    filesPanel.add(calibrationFileSelectionValuePanel,c);

    c.gridy = 1;
   // filesPanel.add(frequencyFileSelection,c);
    filesPanel.add(frequencyFileSelectionValueLabel,c);

    c.gridy = 2;
   // filesPanel.add(sampleFileSelection,c);
    filesPanel.add(sampleFileSelectionValueLabel,c);

    c.gridy = 3;
   // filesPanel.add(outputFileSelection,c);
    filesPanel.add(outputFileSelectionValueLabel,c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    filesPanel.add(calibrationFileSelectionButton,c);

    c.gridy = 1;
    filesPanel.add(frequencyFileSelectionButton,c);      

    c.gridy = 2;
    filesPanel.add(sampleFileSelectionButton,c);

    c.gridy = 3;
    filesPanel.add(createOutputFileButton,c);       

    panelForFilesPanelBorder = new JPanel();
    panelForFilesPanelBorder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,10,5,10), BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()));
    panelForFilesPanelBorder.add(filesPanel);

    buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,10,10,10), BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()));
    buttonsPanel.add(startButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(stopButton);
    basePanel.add(panelForFilesPanelBorder);
    basePanel.add(numericInputPanel); 
    basePanel.add(buttonsPanel);
```

Comment: make a pics, upload it to somewhere else and add it to your question, so we can better understand

Comment: You could set the JLabel's minimum size by calling `setMinimumSize(Dimension d)` which should do what you want.

Comment: hmmm. Well I tried to add an image. I need 10 rep votes apparently.

Comment: Add a link to an image and we can add it to your question for you. What about my suggestion?

Comment: So setMinimumSize() has no affect. I can pass a long blank string to the constructor. That feels cheap though.

Comment: @user2888663, GirdBagLayout generally obeys preferred size. I have added a working example, check it out

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, In this case, with `GridBagLayout` setting minimum size only, will not work. Check my answer for details and point me out if anything i have explained is wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Essentially, GridBagLayout places components in rectangles (cells) in a grid, and then uses the components' *`preferred sizes`* to determine how big the cells should be. *With this layout*:

- if the container's size is *smaller* than the preferred size *only then* the minimum size gets used.
- With empty(`""`) text A `JLabel\JTextFeild\JButton`'s preferred size is around `(2,2)`, if no preferred size hints is given to it explicitly using `setPreferredSize(size)` or overriding `getPreferredSize(size)`.

At his point setting minimum size will not work, as the preferred size with empty text is around `(2,2)` and container's size is already larger than the preferred size. `GridBagLayout` uses the preferred size not worrying about the minimum size at all.

**You actually need to set both preferred and minimum size with `GridBagLayout` because:**

If you try setting  *only* the preferred size, shrinking the size of the window would eventually cause the container panel's size to get shrink. The container's panel size will be *smaller* than the preferred size of the component and the `JLabel\JTextFeild\JButton`  shrink to their minimum size. If you haven't given minimum size hints at this point, the default minimum size: likely to be around `(2,2)` gets used. *You will understand better with given working example below*.

**Some other things to note:**

```
   c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

   // filesPanel.add(calibrationFileSelection,c);
    filesPanel.add(calibrationFileSelectionValuePanel,c);
```

you are adding the `panel` which contains your `calibrationFileSelectionValueLabel`. You don't need to use an extra panel, rather just add the `calibrationFileSelectionValueLabel` directly to the grid by setting( instead overriding `getPreferedSize(Size)` is preferable) `preferredSize`. However try setting inset to the `GridBagConstraints` to look your first `panel` a little more nicer:

```
   gridBagCnst.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
```

**A minimal working example for you:**

In case you are not getting what we are saying, this example i have set only preferred size for  resolving your problem. But as i haven't set minimum size, try resizing the window to match with above explanation.

[image]

**Source code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Rashed
 */
 class GridBagLayoutDemo extends JFrame{


    public JLabel createLabel(String txt, int width, int height, Color color)
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(txt);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(color);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        return label;
    }

    public GridBagLayoutDemo() throws HeadlessException {
      // setSize(400,400);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       JPanel panel = new JPanel(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
       panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
       GridBagConstraints labCnst = new GridBagConstraints();

       Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(140,20);

       labCnst.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);

       JLabel title = new JLabel("My Title");
       JLabel title2 = new JLabel("My Title");
       JLabel title3 = new JLabel("My Title");

       JLabel selectionLabel1 = new JLabel("");
       selectionLabel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
       JLabel selectionLabel2 = new JLabel("");
       selectionLabel2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
       JLabel selectionLabel3 = new JLabel("");
       selectionLabel3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

       selectionLabel1.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
       selectionLabel2.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
       selectionLabel3.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);

       JButton browse1 = new JButton("Browse");
       JButton browse2 = new JButton("Browse");
       JButton browse3 = new JButton("Browse");


        labCnst.gridx = 0;
        labCnst.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(title, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(title2, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(title3, labCnst);

        labCnst.gridx = 1;
        labCnst.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(selectionLabel1, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(selectionLabel2, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(selectionLabel3, labCnst);

        labCnst.gridx = 3;
        labCnst.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(browse1, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(browse2, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(browse3, labCnst);


       //labCnst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;


       add(panel);
       pack();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagLayoutDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I stole your program in my answer and (I think) improved on it a bit by making the labels collapse and expand more naturally when the window is resized.  I gave you credit.

Comment: @MikeClark, It is ok, I won't, as your answer adds more clarification to my explanation :)

Comment: Insets.  You can create all sorts of white space with insets.

Answer (score 6):

Annoyingly, a label with no text will take up no vertical space. You can get around this by using `" "` when it's empty.

```
JLabel fileNameLabel = new JLabel(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified Sage's program using John's `" "` trick and added a little bit of my own `GridBagConstraint` flavoring to make the dialog resize more naturally under collapse and expand.

```
public class GridBagLayoutDemo extends JFrame {

    public GridBagLayoutDemo() throws HeadlessException {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        GridBagConstraints labCnst = new GridBagConstraints();

        Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(140, 1);

        labCnst.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);

        JLabel title = new JLabel("My Title");
        JLabel title2 = new JLabel("My Title");
        JLabel title3 = new JLabel("My Title");

        final JLabel selectionLabel1 = new JLabel(" ");
        selectionLabel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        final JLabel selectionLabel2 = new JLabel(" ");
        selectionLabel2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        final JLabel selectionLabel3 = new JLabel(" ");
        selectionLabel3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        setPreferredWidth(selectionLabel1, 120);
        setPreferredWidth(selectionLabel2, 120);
        setPreferredWidth(selectionLabel3, 120); 

        JButton browse1 = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Browse 1") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                selectionLabel1.setText("C:\\Documents and Settings\\jsmith\\My Documents\\Studio 2014\\Projects\\1");
            }
        });
        JButton browse2 = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Browse 2") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                selectionLabel2.setText("C:\\Documents and Settings\\jsmith\\My Documents\\Studio 2014\\Projects\\2");
            }
        });
        JButton browse3 = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Browse 3") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                selectionLabel3.setText("C:\\Documents and Settings\\jsmith\\My Documents\\Studio 2014\\Projects\\3");
            }
        });

        labCnst.gridx = 0;
        labCnst.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(title, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(title2, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(title3, labCnst);

        labCnst.weightx = 1;
        labCnst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        labCnst.gridx = 1;
        labCnst.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(selectionLabel1, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(selectionLabel2, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(selectionLabel3, labCnst);

        labCnst.weightx = 0;

        labCnst.gridx = 3;
        labCnst.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(browse1, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(browse2, labCnst);
        labCnst.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(browse3, labCnst);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();

    }

    private void setPreferredWidth(JComponent c, int w) {
        Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
        d.width = w;
        c.setPreferredSize(d);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                GridBagLayoutDemo demo = new GridBagLayoutDemo();
                demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: one thing to mention, Jhon's idea is rather a hack complaint avoiding the actual fact. Please don't get me wrong, I personally don't like promoting such idea without explaining the logical inference which is common for all the components rather than any specific type of component :)

Answer (score -1):

As John said, put a single space in the label and/or set it's `setMinimumSize()`.

Minimum size is useful if the label is intended to be populated later, on UI activity.. prevents the UI from compacting into an ugly state when nothing is initially selected.

Comment: So setMinimumSize() has no affect on the space between the first label and the button. I can initialize the label to an empty string of whatever length I need but when my label gets set, if its not the same length, then the spacing between the first label and button might change. I need that to be constant.