# GridBagLayout adhering components

Tags: java, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Take a look on that code:

```
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(buttonMinus,c);

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(labelTime,c);

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(buttonPlus,c);

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    this.add(labelCoor,c);
```

how it looks like now:
[image: now]

how i want to be:
[image: need]

ofc i want to not resize my buttons or labels. let them stay their default sizes.

I know i can do it by adding to the north of `BorderLayout` panel a new `FlowLayout` panel but i want to do it with one `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ofc i want to not resize my buttons or labels. let them stay their default sizes.
```

Then you should set the `weightx = 0, weighty = 0` so that their respective row and col will not get extra space, which you are currently setting to `1`.  Also `GridBagLayout` generally respects *preferred size*, but we should specify both preferred size and minimum size as is explained in [a use case of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738402/how-do-i-get-a-jpanel-with-an-empty-jlabel-to-take-up-space-in-a-gridbaglayout/19739656#19739656). Also take a look to [specifying constraint section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html#gridbagConstraints) of official sources for more details.